# Android unit testing with roboletric

Tags: android, unit-testing, android-studio

We have an Eclipse Android project and we used Roboletric to do unit testing. Now we have port that project into Android Studio and we want to fit Roboletric into the project. I have searched on the web and it seems that it is quite hard to use Roboletric in Android Studio. I want to know if trying to use Roboletric is the right choice now. If not, what could be a good choice to do unit testing in Android Studio?